# Unix cp command not transferring 777 permission?

Tags: unix

I've been using cp -r to duplicate some things in my file system and something bizarre keeps happening...certain directories that are permissioned as 777 have more secure permissions in the target directories I am copying to.

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cp -a might resolve your situation, you need to tell cp to preserve the permissions so that it doesn't inherit them from your umask.

Comment: Indeed it does. Editing my response.